I need help identifying a scroll artist
I have a scroll with a notes that describes it and names the artist as Ichijusai Yoshikazu.  I tried to use Google Lens to translate, It didn't match the description but I do not trust it.  When searching the artist I could not find a match for the red seal.  Any help would be appreciated, thank you!


This isn’t a Chinese language question. Here’s a Japanese article on the artist - we can’t help you further.

It is a Japanese painting with Chinese lettering. From the column at the right to the left:

南無妙法蓮"華(?)"經

清正公大神儀


The signature:

一壽齋芳員謹畫


謹畫 means 'respectfully drawn' 一壽齋 is the last name 芳員 is the first name,

Does anybody recognize the character after "蓮"? "華" was a guess.

Both 華 and 花 mean flowers in ancient times. 蓮華 = 蓮花  (lotus flower), you guessed right

一壽齋  seems to be a title or pen name

@TangHo XX齋 sounds loke the name of the workshop(書/字畫坊).

一壽齋 - Utagawa (Ichijusai) Kunitsuru (一壽齋國鶴 1807-78; family name Wada 和田; personal name Yasugorô 安五郎, Seem like many people having一壽齋 in front of their name, a workshop's name became a title maybe.
